# Obtener el numero de resultados encontrados de una consulta mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente consulta para mostrar ciertos empleados en especifico

```
<div class="row">
<?php
$row_cnt = 0;
                  
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2) ) {
$no_=$row["codigo_persona"];
$hora = "SELECT * FROM workin,meta WHERE employee = '".$no_."' AND type = categoria";
$horaxhora = $mysqli->query($hora);

while( $serial = mysqli_fetch_assoc($horaxhora) ) {
$us = "SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) FROM empleados,seriales WHERE codigo_persona = '".$no_."' AND user_n = user_name GROUP BY user_name";
$userno = $mysqli->query($us);
var_dump ($serial);
```

Al correr esta parte de codigo el resultado que obtengo es mi principal.php es el siguiente 4 empleados cumplen con la consulta pero lo que yo quiero hacer ahora es como puedo mostrar el resultado en numero por ejemplo la consulta me mostro 4 empleados yo quiero obtener el numero de empleados encotrados ya lo intente con `$row_cnt = $horaxhora->num_rows;` pero solo me da como resultado 1.

De igual manera agrego el resultado de la consulta mediante un var_dump en el que llamo a la variable `$horaxhora`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si el var_dump llamo a la variable `$serial` obtengo los siguientes resultados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta count($horaxhora) o count((array)$horaxhora)

Comment: @Carmen seria de la siguiente manera entonces `$row_cnt = count($horaxhora)->num_rows` o entendi mal?

Comment: sólo el count, sería $row_cnt = count($horaxhora)

Comment: @Carmen no me muestra ningun resultado solo el siguiente error `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, mysqli_result given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pickeo\principal.php:223 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pickeo\principal.php on line 223`

Comment: @Carmen y si lo intento con `count((array)$horaxhora)` no me da error pero el resultado queda en 0

Comment: puedes intentarlo con $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($horaxhora); referencia https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

Comment: me da como resultado solo `1` al igual que `$row_cnt = $horaxhora->num_rows;`

Comment: pues sin más datos no se me ocurren más opciones, tendrías que editar la pregunta e incluir el resultado obtenido de la query, por ejemplo con un var_dump, ya que parece como si trajera un único resultado.

Comment: @carmen ya agregue el resultado del var_dump

Comment: Prueba haciendo lo que te indicaron pero fuera del `while`.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev ya lo hice y continua igual si lo intento con `$row_cnt = count($horaxhora);` me da el error de un comentario mas arriba y si lo intento con `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($horaxhora);` el valor es `0`

Comment: Esto no parece una buena idea: dos consultas anidadas en dos bucles. Si el bucle 1 tiene `N` elementos y el bucle 2 tiene `M` estaríamos hablando de `N x M` consultas, y `N` y `M` pueden ser cualquier cosa. Podríamos estar hablando de miles o de millones de consultas en algunos casos. Me pregunto, ¿qué es lo que quieres lograr exactamente y por qué no escribes una sola consulta que te traiga todo lo que necesitas, aprovechando además los índices que habrás puesto, supongo, de forma adecuada en tus tablas?

Comment: @A.Cedano tenias razon mi problema era los bucles me disculpo gracias por el comentario ya consolide todo en una sola consulta y funciono correctamente ya me muestra los 4

Comment: Excelente, me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Ten en cuenta que puedes responder a tu propia pregunta si lo consideras oportuno, explicando cómo resolviste el problema y cómo queda el código, por si puede servir a futuros usuarios con problemas similares.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion a mi problema fue de la manera en como me aconcejo A.cedeno

Concentre todas mis consultas en una sola y en un solo while

La consulta quedo de la siguiente manera para extraer los datos necesarios

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Nombre,Puesto,Imagen,cantidad,user_name, COUNT(*) FROM empleados,certificaciones,workin,meta,seriales 
WHERE empleado_id = codigo_persona AND Certificacion IN ('Montacargas', 'Picker') 
AND employee = codigo_persona AND type = meta.categoria AND user_n = user_name GROUP BY user_name";

$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($resultado2);
```

Y el resultado obtenido fue el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de esta manera pude obtener el numero de registros obtenidos de la consulta y asi poder calcular el promedio general de productividad